# Freeze Ubuntu for one application (Kiosk Mode or General Purpose Computer)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-standard-base

I don't know, what exactly called this process...help me also by editing my question
I want to freeze my Ubuntu for one application, which means only that application can view on that ubuntu...

Can you please help me to do that because I have no idea how to do that, but I just heard about that?

Comment: Do you mean Kiosk Mode?

Comment: @apesa I just read about Kiosk Mode... Yes my requirement is kiosk mode in Ubuntu which ony run one application... Thank you

Comment: Look here or just Google "Ubuntu Kiosk Mode" http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/  Good Luck

Comment: This is an operating system question, not a programming question, and therefore it's off-topic here.